# Counting changes of value in each column in a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any neat way to count the number of changes of value in each column in a data frame in pandas?

I don't want to have to loop myself over each column, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[1234567000,1234567005,1234567009],
    'X1':[96.32,96.01,96.05],
    'X2':[23.88,23.96,23.96]
},columns=['time','X1','X2']) 

print(frame)

changes = []
for column_name in frame.columns.values:
    print('column_name: {0}'.format(column_name))
    changes.append(sum(frame[column_name]!=frame[column_name].shift(1)))

print('changes: {0}'.format(changes))
```

returns:

```
         time     X1     X2
0  1234567000  96.32  23.88
1  1234567005  96.01  23.96
2  1234567009  96.05  23.96
column_name: time
column_name: X1
column_name: X2
changes: [3, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the values are numeric you could take the differences between adjacent rows and test if the difference is non-zero. Then take a sum down each column to count the number of changes in value:

```
In [48]: (frame.diff(axis=0) != 0).sum(axis=0)
Out[48]: 
time    3
X1      3
X2      2
dtype: int64
```

If the values are not necessarily numeric, then a more general way would be to
compare the `frame` against itself `shift`-ed down by one row -- this is similar to the code you posted, except the operation is done on the entire DataFrame instead of column-by-column:

```
In [50]: (frame != frame.shift(axis=0)).sum(axis=0)
Out[50]: 
time    3
X1      3
X2      2
dtype: int64
```

The numeric version is faster, the shifted version is more robust.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up: [Counting changes of value in each column in a data frame in pandas ignoring NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45038037/395857)